# FileSystemAccessAPI opens system file picker, but doesn't write to file

Tags: javascript, html, file-system-access-api

I have an HTML form (running locally) that I want to dump its output to a user-specified location on their local drive. I format the fields as a string (`contents`), and then I pass it to this JS code:

*writeFile.js*

```
    // Create a handle; allow user to pick their file.
    const fileHandle = await window.showSaveFilePicker();

    // Create a FileSystemWritableFileStream to write to.
    const writableStream = await fileHandle.createWritable();

    // Write the prepared contents of the file to the stream.
    await writableStream.write(contents);

    // Close the file and write the contents to disk.
    await writableStream.close();
```

I then implement this in the HTML code as a button, which I believe works as it should:

*form.html*

```
    <input id="download_path" type="submit" class="btn" style="width: 125px" onclick="writeFile();" />
```

This is a direct implementation of this "Concepts and Usage" section of the MDN Web Docs

The Windows save dialog opens, allows user to save the file, but the file is blank. I have also tried replacing `contents` with a literal string, which doesn't show up in the file. I'm not sure what other methods to debug there are, as I very rarely develop webapps (although I know they exist).

My thoughts are that since this API is limited to secure contexts only (https://), it cannot run on a local html file (file:///). But shouldn't there be a way for a local HTML file to bypass this, since it is in a closed system?

Browser: Chrome 88.0.4324.182

Windows Version: Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 0):

This [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) is required over secure context. What I do when I need to run something that requires secure context, I use [repl.it](https://repl.it) because they have an inbuilt code editor that updates on the website instantly. You could also use localhost with secure context, which you can learn about [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/). Also try changing:

```html
<input id="download_path" type="submit" class="btn" style="width: 125px" onclick="writeFile();" />
```

to:

```html
<input id="download_path" type="button" class="btn" style="width: 125px" onclick="writeFile();" value="Hello" />
```

or to:

```html
<button id="download_path" class="btn" style="width: 125px" onclick="writeFile();">Hello</button>
```

Comment: I tried this on a different computer and I was able to get it working with the `file:///` protocol. Very strange -- I'm still not sure why it would be different here.

Comment: Here's an important piece of information from the FileSystemAccessAPI docs: "Locally-delivered resources such as those with http://127.0.0.1 URLs, http://localhost and  http://*.localhost URLs (e.g. http://dev.whatever.localhost/), and file:// URLs are also considered to have been delivered securely." Also, logging window.isSecureContext returns true.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue -- I had my button inside the `<form>` element, which was preventing it from fully executing. It would open the save dialog, but the file would be empty. Strangely, moving the button outside this makes it work perfectly now.